# How to extract 10 digit number excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have rows in my columns like below, I need to extract 15 digit numbers from that. Only common thing between rows is all 15 digit numbers starts and ends with dash(_).

> ABCD_AB0121_01_201602050716356_ABCD_ABDE
>     BCD_AB0121_01_201602050716356_ABCD
>     ABCD_AB0121_01_201502050716356_ABCD_ABDE
>   BCD_AB0121_01_201402050716356_ABCD

Comment: Is it always after the 3rd "_"?

Comment: No unfortunately it's different sometimes.

Comment: what about _2016? Maybe an increased sample would be helpful. We may find something helpful.

Comment: all numbers starts with either of these _2014, _2015, _2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following formula in `Cell B1` :

```
=LOOKUP(10^15,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),15)+0)
```

See image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "_20" appears **only** at the start of every 15 digit number and the string from which to be extracted is in column A, a simple MID with FIND should do:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("_20",A2)+1,15)
```

Comment: Thank you very much